# Why transition is not working when I switching off animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition

I want to make a thing when you click to button 'off' :

- lights must fade out smoothly.

I put to my CSS class 'light' attribute: `transition 1s all`. But nothing happened.
The lights fade out very fast and without a smooth effect. I want to make the switch off with JS.

```js
const lights = document.querySelectorAll(".light");
const buttonOn = document.querySelector(".on");
const buttonOff = document.querySelector(".off");

buttonOff.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let light of lights) {
    light.style.animation = 'none';
    light.style.background = "#563260";
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 1460px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 7rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px wht;
}

.panel {
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid violet;
}

.light {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.light::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.light::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -70px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 87px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid brown;
}

.light:first-child::after {
  width: 0;
}

.purple {
  animation-name: purple;
}

.green {
  animation-name: green;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.pink {
  animation-name: pink;
}

.yellow {
  animation-name: yellow;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes purple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgb(29, 2, 49);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(91, 9, 150);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px indigo;
  }
}

@keyframes green {
  0% {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgb(3, 58, 10);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(49, 206, 10);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgb(36, 228, 10);
  }
}

@keyframes pink {
  0% {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgb(71, 4, 51);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(214, 13, 154);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgb(202, 17, 147);
  }
}

@keyframes yellow {
  0% {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgb(56, 56, 2);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(212, 212, 7);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgb(240, 240, 13);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,regular,italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="light purple"></div>
      <div class="light green"></div>
      <div class="light pink"></div>
      <div class="light yellow"></div>
      <div class="light purple"></div>
      <div class="light green"></div>
      <div class="light pink"></div>
      <div class="light yellow"></div>
      <div class="light purple"></div>
      <div class="light green"></div>
      <div class="light pink"></div>
      <div class="light yellow"></div>
      <div class="light purple"></div>
      <div class="light green"></div>
      <div class="light pink"></div>
      <div class="light yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">Christmas Lights</h1>
    <div class="panel">
        <a href="#" class="button on">On</a>
        <a href="#" class="button off">Off</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are confusing animation and transition. Switching off animation has no effect on transitioned properties. Transitions are when previously set styles are changed to other values.

Comment: @ScottMarcus okay, but how can I make smoothly stopping animation?

Comment: thanks for the help, found the issue.